# CollectionView MAUI - How to refresh list if item source contains Model.Property (list in my case)

Tags: c#, maui

How to refresh list if item source contains Model.Property (list in my case):

my model is:

```
public class User
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public required string LoginName { get; set; }
public required string FullName { get; set; }
public required string Email { get; set; }
public required string PasswordHash { get; set; }
public bool Active { get; set; } = true;
[NotMapped]
public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

in my content page i have:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding User.Roles}"
            SelectionMode="Single">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding Name }"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               FontSize="12"
               VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

i use MVVM and in my VM i have:

```
[ObservableProperty] private User _user;
```

when i add a role to my User.roles, roles is updated but collectionview not refresh my user list of role with new role added.

How to do that?

Thanks in advance,
B.G.

Im not found something like this.your text

Comment: Except for using `ObserveableCollection` your code already looks correct, what issue are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change the List to [ObservableCollecion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0). Such as:

```
[NotMapped]
public ObservableCollecion<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

Comment: **This did the job. Thanks a lot.**

Answer (score 0):

make changes:

```html
[NotMapped]
public List<Role> Roles { get; set; } = new list<Role>();
```

```html
_user.Roles.Add(new Role { Name = "New Role" });
```

Comment: my problem is not how to add role but how to view added role in collectionview. Thanks anyway.